# Revisiting: Should questions about data visualization be considered on topic?

Tags: discussion

From a search, it appears the last time this question was posed was [four years ago](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/are-data-visualization-questions-on-topic) -- since then, data visualization has matured as a field a great deal, with a fledgling ecosystem of [open source tools](http://dataviz.tools) democratizing the process and, often, removing the need to code altogether.

Obviously, a programming question on, say, d3.js wouldn't be on topic, but what about questions on low-level data viz tools, visualization best practices, gestalt principles, visual cognition, etc.?

There is no dedicated data visualization SE at present, so I'm wondering: If not here, where?

Comment: I had proposed a site for dataviz but it never got enough attention. maybe it's time again.

Answer (score 3):

This forum is dedicated to open data, and questions about a use of visualization tools in interpreting a type of data (or a specific dataset) would make sense to post here.  General questions about the tool or best practices would likely not be appropriate or get the responses you need. You might want to check out the StackExchange [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (on statistics), which has several questions on data visualization and tools.